# Is this literal or code in the .htaccess file?

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting, regex

Background: Recently, a business acquaintance contacted me because of strange behavior on his website. As may be expected, I found that the site was compromised.

One of the signs of the compromise is changes in his `.htaccess` file, which is fairly common. I have only done a little bit of regex, but I'm familiar with the `[0-9]` construct. However, I found a `RewriteRule` that seems to have a literal number.

```
RewriteRule ^5014466727/(.*)$ jabez-darla.php [QSA,L]
```

Question: Do I understand correctly, that this rule is looking for a match on a URL that literally has `5014466727/` or does this represent some string of other characters?

There is base64 in other parts of the compromise, but I don't know whether that is relevant in this specific code.

Comment: You understand it correctly. It is a literal string of numbers. Cheers!!

Comment: As @closetnoc says (may as well add that as an answer :). Is there anything else to this rule, ie. any `RewriteCond` directives that precede it? (Just that the `(.*)$` bit is entirely superfluous otherwise.) The seemingly random number (per site/hack) is probably just to make this harder to Google. "looking for a match on a file name" - strictly speaking it's a match on a URL, not necessarily a "file name".

Comment: After the compromise, the first two lines in the .htaccess file were

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^5014466727/(.*)$ jabez-darla.php [QSA,L]

There are further directives below. The final set is the standard WordPress permalink settings.

I will change my question. You are correct that it's not part of a file name. I missed that detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^5014466727/(.*)$ jabez-darla.php [QSA,L]
> ```
>
> ...this rule is looking for a match on a URL that literally has 5014466727/

Yes, as closetnoc stated in comments, this is simply a literal string of (seemingly random) digits at the *start* of the URL.

Since the captured group (ie. `(.*)`) does not appear to be used in the *substitution* (or in any preceding `RewriteCond` directives), the pattern `^5014466727/(.*)$` is equivalent to `^5014466727/`.

The seemingly random number (which might be unique per site/hack) is probably just to make this harder to find in the search engines.